# Find someone on Facebook using their Major and School?

Tags: facebook

I know someone's major and university, for example on the left side of their homepage it will say:

Studied *Blah Blah* at *xyz* University

I can't really recall their full name and would like to find them, so how can I filter it to just search based on their major and school?

Comment: This might help you http://science.opposingviews.com/someone-facebook-dont-remember-name-21636.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can try just searching.

```
people who studied political science at george washington university
```

Gives me a whole bunch of people. Probably too many. If you remember a first name that should narrow your search.

```
people who studied political science at george washington university named mary
```

Facebook will probably re-phrase your search, but it does a pretty good job sussing out what you're looking for.

Of course, this all pre-supposes that the person you're looking for has their privacy settings configured so that they can be found this way.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work anymore! Facebook only searches for people's names then you have to specify the school or location etc.. Which is painfully frustrating.